# Using `select` clause along with `includes` and `references`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
class Order <  < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # total
  # customer_id
  # custom_field1
  # custom_field2
  # custom_field3
  # custom_field4

  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I want to query the line items for a specific customer and eager load the `order` for each line item. I don't want to include the custom fields in `order` model while eager loading.

I tried using the following query:

```
LineItem.
  includes(:order).
  references(:order).
  where(customer_id: 2).
  select("line_items.*, orders.id, orders.total, orders.customer_id")
```

The SQL generated by Rails has all the columns from `LineItem`, `Order` and the explicitly `select`ed columns.

How do I restrict the column set returned when using `includes` + `references`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `pluck` instead:

```
LineItem.
  includes(:order).
  references(:order).
  where(customer_id: 2).
  pluck(#the attributes you need here)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: I can't use pluck as I want to get AR objects back and traverse the associations.